# I am trying to write an app for different platforms

Tags: java, android, html, jakarta-ee, symbian

We can use html5/javascript for android,iOS, windows phone, 
that part i finished already. I want to develop the same app for other platforms like symbian,bada and so on.

I would like to which all languages/tutorials link so can learn to 
develop the same.

Basically what i thought i ll use Mosync/ phoneGap. so wanna know if 
any other such similiar platforms(software) is available to develop
cross- platform apllication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely PhoneGap which I recommend.
And then there is Worklight by IBM for Cross Platform Applications.